# Pytest: Splitting big test file into multiple files

Tags: python, pytest

I have a Pytest file where I connect to a database, retrieve it's content, write it as sql commands and fire it to another DB.

I want to split the file into 3 files:

- conftest.py: where I store the db connection
- querytest.py: Where I transform the file into sql commands
- test.py: Where I execute the pytest

They are all in the same 'test' directory.

My problem is if I execute the code in one file it, Pytest works. But if I separat it into these 3 files I get `

```
Test result not found for: ./tests/test.py
```

I'm currently using a fixture for the connection and the final list with the commands. I have tried to import the module from the file and declare it under parametrize. But it still didn't work. Any Idea why?

Comment: if you're still unable to find the problem, I'd suggest updating the question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I was able to solve it. It was a bug with VS Code. After restarting, pytest worked normally or at least showed the real error message.